# Owerride operator from base class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have two class A and B. I want that B class extent A and add z parameter.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
 public:
    A()
    {}

    ~A(){}
    virtual bool operator<(const A<T>& lhs) const
    {
        return ( (x < lhs->getX()) && (y < lhs->getY()) );
    }
    const T getX()
    {
     return x;   
    }

    const T getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
private:
    const T x;
    const T y;


};


template<typename T,typename  Z>
class B: public   A<T>
{
 public:
   B()
    {}

    ~B(){}
    bool operator<(const B<T,Z>& lhs) const
    {
        return ( (x < lhs->getX()) && (y < lhs->getY()) , (z < lhs->getZ()));
    }

    const T getZ()
    {
        return z;
    }
private:
    const T z;

};
```

I try compile this but doesn't work. I get listed below error:

```
In member function 'bool B<T, Z>::operator<(const B<T, Z>&) const': 
40:13: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope 
40:34: error: 'y' was not declared in this scope
```

I want to overloading operator < in class B. How is it possible? I use C++14 compiler.

Comment: `x` / `y` need to be protected not private if you want derived classes to be able to access them. Alternatively call `getX()` / `getY()` from the derived class. (It's also possible you need to call prefix with `this->`)

Comment: or better yet, call `A::operator<` from `B::operator<`

Comment: Note that `( (x < lhs->getX()) && (y < lhs->getY()) , (z < lhs->getZ()))`  is equivalent to `z < lhs->getZ()`, and that the operator doesn't override the one in the base class.

Comment: You should also consider what "less than" means for an `A`. `(0,0)` is less than `(1,1)`, but what about `(0,1)`?

Comment: Sholud I write: `return (A<T>::operator<(lhs) && z < lhs->getZ()); ` ?

Comment: If that's the behavior you want, sure. But do consider @BoPersson's earlier comment.

Comment: @bo-persson I want that A(0,0) is less tan (1,1) and A(0,0) less than (0,1)